# Как упростить работу с SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hibernate

Возможно ли использовать высокоуровневые средства работы с SQLite? Например, я использовал ORM Hibernate для работы с PostgreSQL. Есть ли что-то подобное для SQLite, чтобы не писать миллион строчек, используя JDBC API?

Comment: https://ormlite.com/

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Под андроид стандарт - это либа room от гугла

Comment: Большое спасибо!